# Does $A^{m} \le A^{n}$ hold for operators when $A \ge 1$ and $m \le n$?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

Let $A$ be a symmetric bounded linear operator on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. Suppose that $A \ge 1$, in the sense that $\langle \psi, A\psi\rangle \ge \|\psi\|^{2}$, for all $0 \neq \psi \in \mathscr{H}$.Question: if $m \le n$ with $m$ and $n$ being nonnegative rational numbers, does it follow that $A^{m} \le A^{n}$ in the sense that $\langle \psi, A^{n}\psi\rangle \ge \langle \psi, A^{m}\psi\rangle$? It seems reasonable to think the answer is *yes*, but I was not able to prove it myself.

Comment: Confusing... $A$ is only "densely defined"  but the definition for $A \ge 1$ requires $A\psi$ for all $\psi$.

Comment: @GEdgar true, sorry. Fixed it. I actually want to prove it only for bounded linear operators anyway.

Comment: Yes. I am actually interested in the case $A$ is self-adjoint, but let us make it more general and assume it is symmetric. I edited the post again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a partial answer, too long for a comment.

If $n=m$ the result is trivial.

If $n$ is odd, i.e. $n=2k+1>m$, then
\begin{align*}
\langle \psi, A^n \psi\rangle &= \langle A^k\psi, A A^k\psi\rangle\\
&\geq \langle A^k\psi, A^k\psi\rangle\\
&=\langle \psi, A^{n-1}\psi\rangle
\end{align*}

If $n$ is even, i.e. $n=2(k+1)>m\geq 0$, then suppose we know the fact that $\langle \psi, A^2 \psi\rangle \geq \langle \psi, A \psi \rangle$, then we get similar result
\begin{align*}
\langle \psi, A^n \psi\rangle &= \langle A^k\psi, A^2 A^k\psi\rangle\\
&\geq \langle A^k\psi, A A^k\psi\rangle\\
&= \langle \psi, A^{n-1}\psi\rangle\\
\end{align*}

Alternating between those two steps until $n$ is decreased to $m$ gives your result.

It remains therefore to prove that for any $\psi$, $\langle \psi, A^2 \psi\rangle \geq \langle \psi, A \psi \rangle$.

Comment: Also since $(A-I)^2\geq 0$ we have that $$\langle \psi, A^2 \psi \rangle \geq \langle \psi, (2A - I) \psi \rangle = \langle \psi, (A-I) \psi \rangle + \langle \psi, A \psi \rangle \geq \langle \psi, A \psi \rangle$$ where for the last step we use that $A\geq I$.

Comment: @NicolasAgote Very nice, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

For any polynomial $p$ with nonnegative coefficients and a positive operator $B$ we have $p(B)\ge 0,$  because $B^k\ge 0$ for any $k.$ The polynomial $$p_n(x)=(1+x)^{n}-(1+x)^{n-1}=x(1+x)^{n-1}$$ has nonnegative coefficients. By assumptions  $A=I+B$ where  $B\ge 0.$ Hence $$A^{n}-A^{n-1}=(I+B)^{n}-(I+B)^{n-1}=p_n(B)\ge 0$$ Since the relation $\ge $ is transitive we get $A^n\ge A^m$ for $n\ge m.$

For positive rational numbers we will use the fact: if $A\ge I$ then $A^{1/n}\ge I.$ For ${p\over q}\ge {r\over s}\ge 0$ we have ${ps\over qs}\ge {qr\over qs}.$ Since $A^{1/qs}\ge I$ and $ps\ge qr$ we get by the first part applied to $A^{1/qs}$ that $$A^{p/q}=A^{ps/qs}\ge A^{qr/qs}=A^{r/s}$$
**Remark** The result is easy if we may use the functional calculus for selfadjoint operators.